# Open URL in XE6 firemonkey IOS-DELPHI

Tags: android, ios, firemonkey

Good Morning,

I'm trying to do a cross-platform application for both android and IOS to open a URL that will pass as parameter in the default browser in android I have achieved using the following code:

```
 { Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
  TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString
  ('http://www.***.com'));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent); }
```

But in IOS do not know how to open a URL in the default browser, I searched thousands of pages that use methods but none have helped me, if you could help me I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the happy path for what I did (excluding error handling, etc.)

```
uses
 //...
 IdURI,
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Androidapi.Helpers, FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, 
  Androidapi.JNI.App, Androidapi.JNI.Net, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes
{$ENDIF ANDROID}

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Winapi.ShellAPI, Winapi.Windows
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

{$IFDEF IOS}
    Macapi.Helpers, iOSapi.Foundation, FMX.Helpers.iOS
{$ENDIF IOS}
    ;
```

and

```
//...
procedure TForm1.launchBrowser();
var
  myURL: string;
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Intent: JIntent;
{$ENDIF ANDROID}

{$IFDEF IOS}
  NSU: NSUrl;
{$ENDIF IOS}
begin
  myURL := 'http://www.example.com';
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  ShellExecute(0, 'OPEN', PChar(myURL), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

{$IFDEF IOS}
  NSU   := StrToNSUrl(TIdURI.URLEncode(myURL));
  if SharedApplication.canOpenURL(NSU) then
  begin
    SharedApplication.openUrl(NSU);
  end;
{$ENDIF IOS}

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  Intent.setData(StrToJURI(myURL));
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(Intent);
{$ENDIF ANDROID}
end;
```

Note: "SharedActivity" has been deprecated (at least in 10/Seatle). The replacement seems to be "TAndroidHelper.Activity"

Comment: SharedActivity still works for me in Delphi 10 Seattle

Comment: @Remi - you're right, it does work - but I get the following warning "[DCC Warning] FILENAME.pas(line#): W1000 Symbol 'SharedActivity' is deprecated: 'Use TAndroidHelper.Activity'" when you build in Delphi 10 Seattle. And since I like having my compiles warning less, I chose to fix it now rather than wait for it to be expunged by Embarcadero later :^)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do it that way. Works perfect for me:

http://delphi.org/2013/10/sending-a-url-to-another-app-on-android-and-ios-with-delphi-xe5/

Comment: Sadly, the URL you posted for the accepted answer is now returning '404 not found'

Answer (score 1):

```
uses Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var   Intent: JIntent;
begin
   Intent := TJIntent.Create;
   Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
   Intent.setData(StrToJURI('http://www.website.com.br/index.php'));
   SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```